# Android SharedPreferences Performance

Tags: java, android, performance, sharedpreferences

Recently I found my App blocks at **monitor contention** on app start, when I read values on multiple threads.
I found that the Android `SharedPreferencesImpl` use seperate lock for read and write operations. 
But why they do not use a more efficient and higher throughput implementation, like ReentrantReadWriteLock or non-block read to improve the concurrent read throughput?

The newest SharedPreferencesImpl use `mEditorLock` for write and `mLock` for read:

```java
public String getString(String key, String defValue) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        ...
    }
}

public Editor putString(String key, String value) {
    synchronized (mEditorLock) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Why not Use ReentrantReadWriteLock or CAS for better performance? for example:

```java
public String getString(String key, String defValue) {
    readWriteLock.readLock().lock()

    try {
        ...
    } finaly {
        readWriteLock.readLock().unlock()
    }
}

public Editor putString(String key, String value) {
    readWriteLock.writeLock().lock()

    try {
        ...
    } finaly {
        readWriteLock.writeLock().unlock()
    }
}
```

[Newest SharedPreferencesImpl Source Code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java)

Comment: Shared preferences were designed to store simple values that represent settings or app states like dismissed dialogs and are usually only accessed from single UI thread. I believe high multi-threaded throughput was not a design concern.